# JSF Model Beans are not updated for Dynamically Created Form Fields

Tags: jsf, primefaces, mojarra

I have a form where some form fields are dynamically generated based on the selected product by the user. When users selects a product, attributes of product are fetched from the database and corresponding form fields are added to view. When form is submitted, the values of the dynamically added fields are also sent to server. However, model objects holding the values of the dynamic fields **are not updated**.(ViewScoped is used)
I have tried both ui:repeat and p:dataGrid.(I read ui:repeat implementation of mojarra is problematic) Nothing changed.

Below you can see the facelet creating the dynamic fields.When attributes list is updated, 'attributeFilterPanel' is updated with ajax call.

attributeFilters is a Map. For each attribute, filters map is prepopulated with an entry using attribute.name as the key.

Any help is really appreciated. 
Thank you.

Note: I am running Mojarra 2.2.12.

```
    <h:panelGroup id="attributeFilterPanel">
    <h:panelGroup id="filtersGroup" rendered="#{not empty attributes }">
        <p:dataGrid columns="3" var="attribute" value="#{attributes}" layout="grid" paginator="false">
            <h:panelGroup>
                <p:outputLabel value="#{attribute.label}"/>

                <p:selectOneMenu id="match_mode_${attribute.name}"
                                 rendered="#{attribute.valueType =='STRING'}"
                                 value="#{attributeFilters[attribute.name].matchMode}">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="EQUALS" itemLabel="#{msg.equals}"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="CONTAINS" itemLabel="#{msg.contains}"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="STARTS_WITH" itemLabel="#{msg.startsWith}"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="ENDS_WITH" itemLabel="#{msg.endsWith}"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <p:selectOneMenu id="amatch_mode_${attribute.name}"
                                 rendered="#{attribute.valueType =='INTEGER' or attribute.valueType == 'NUMERIC'}"
                                 value="#{attributeFilters[attribute.name].matchMode}">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="EQUALS" itemLabel="#{msg.equals}"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="LESS_OR_EQUAL" itemLabel="#{msg.lessOrEqual}"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="GREATER_OR_EQUAL" itemLabel="#{msg.greaterOrEqual}"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>



                <p:inputText id="sattribute_${attribute.name}"
                             rendered="#{attribute.valueType =='STRING'}"
                             value="#{attributeFilters[attribute.name].value}"/>
                <p:inputNumber id="iattribute_${attribute.name}"
                               rendered="#{attribute.valueType == 'INTEGER'}" decimalPlaces="0"
                               value="#{attributeFilters[attribute.name].value}"/>
                <p:inputNumber id="nattribute_${attribute.name}"
                               rendered="#{attribute.valueType == 'NUMERIC'}" decimalPlaces="3"
                               value="#{attributeFilters[attribute.name].value}"/>
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="battribute_${attribute.name}"
                                         rendered="#{attribute.valueType == 'BOOLEAN'}"
                                         value="#{attributeFilters[attribute.name].value}"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </p:dataGrid>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Filter is a simple pojo.

```
public class Filter {
private String name;
private Object value;
private MatchMode matchMode;

public Filter(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.matchMode = MatchMode.EQUALS;
}


public void setValue(Object value) {
    this.value = value;
}
public Object getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setMatchMode(MatchMode matchMode) {
    this.matchMode = matchMode;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}


public MatchMode getMatchMode() {
    return matchMode;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I can get it working is adding ajax value change events for each form field. Models beans are updated with ajax updates. It is strage that model beans are not updated with post requests but value change events are reflected.

```
<p:ajax event="valueChange" process="@this"
                                    update="@widgetVar(productAttibuteGrid)"/>
```